# What can you coat/seal Gallium with?

Tags: heat-transfer, heat

If I were to make a sculpture out of Gallium, Ga melts at about 85 °F I think, would I be able to spray it with some sort of solvent based or not solvent based coating to help prevent it from breaking or heating up when holding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is a perfect insulator. There is no perfect insulator, let alone a thin film liquid kind. If ambient temperature is even on iota higher than the melting temperature, eventually it will reach that and melt.

If the magic spray you're looking for existed you could make ice cubes that would never melt at room temperature, or super conductors that would never heat up at room temperature!

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to find a coating of any sort that insulates the item from thermal changes as a result of holding it.

How does one prevent an element from melting at 85 °F? Enclose it in a cooling chamber, perhaps a Peltier effect device providing lower temperatures within the transparent cylinder.